# How to Plot heat map for the given dataset using R

Tags: r

How can i plot heatmap for the following data with ID in  Y-axis  and its corresponding names in the X axis

```
  ID       Name1      Name2       Name3        Name4     Name5    Name6
  Gp2      2,86148    7,86926     5,00778      3,6586    5,66554  2,00694
 Cldn10    3,30779    8,03876     4,73097      4,4237    7,96975  3,54605
 Cldn10    4,261      8,7293      4,4683       4,3483    9,03017  4,68187
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, so that we can provide targeted help. Just using the default way of plotting a heatmap works directly with your data.

Comment: Did you try it before? http://flowingdata.com/2010/01/21/how-to-make-a-heatmap-a-quick-and-easy-solution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`read.table`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) allows you to specify that the data contains a header and row names:

```
x = read.table('filename', header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
heatmap(as.matrix(x))
```

This assumes that the data does not contain `','` as a thousands separator. If you want to use `,` as decimal point, just specify the appropriate option:

```
x = read.table('filename', header = TRUE, row.names = 1, dec = ',')
```

If your input data contains commas as thousands separators, you need to remove them first:

```
raw_data = readLines('filename')
raw_data = gsub('(\\d+),(\\d+)', '\\1\\2', raw_data)
x = read.table(text = raw_data, header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
```

Comment: Error: 'x' must be a numeric matrix

Comment: @beginner You still have the commas in the number, haven’t you?

Comment: Yes, but actually i need this to be as decimals. is there any way to transform

Comment: @beginner See updated answer. Note that this would have been obvious by looking at the documentation, which you should  **always** do first when using a new functionality.